# Unhandled exception at 0x003714e9 in Quick.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow

Tags: c++, visual-c++, stack-overflow

This never happened to me and I got no idea how to fix it. It just says "Unhandled exception at 0x003714e9 in Quick.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow." then breaks and it highlights the bracket and shows an arrow next to it which I think it means that the error is located there. 
P.S. The bracket is in bold

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int partition(int data[], int left, int right)
**{**
    int pivot = data[left];
    while(true)
    {
        while(data[left] < pivot)
        { 
            left++;
        }
        while (data[right]>pivot)
        {
            //find smaller value than pivot from top array
            right--;
        }

        if(left < right)
        {
            //change pivot place
            int temp = data[right];
            data[right] = data[left];
            data[left] = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            return right;
        }
    }
}

void quickSort (int *data, int left, int right)
{

    if(left<right)
    {
        int cut = partition(data, left, right);
        if(cut>1)
        {
            quickSort(data, left, right);
        }
        if(cut+1<right)
        {
        quickSort(data, cut+1, right);
        }
    }
}

void quickSort(int *data, int length)
{
    quickSort(data, length-length, length-1);
}


void print_array(int array[], int size) //this function is to print the array after we finish sorting and we can use it before the sorting begin
{
    int j;
    for (j=0; j<size; j++)
    cout <<" "<< array[j]<<endl;

}//end of print_array

int main()
{
    const int size = 5;
    int arr[size]= {1, 17, 4, 6, 20};
    quickSort(arr, 0, size); 
    print_array(arr, size);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Most likely uncontrolled recursion. Make sure your base case is sound

Comment: Well I checked everything but I can't see an error, not that my code is perfect but I am blind right now :P

Comment: I suggest you to insert a Tracepoint in Visual Studio, checking "Print a message" and then input `{$CALLSTACK}` at your quicksort function. It will turn the execution slow, but you will get the log of the calls on the Output window.

Comment: I am not on that level I am still a beginner, so I don't know what are you talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem lies in here:

```
if(cut>1)
{
    quickSort(data, left, right);
}
```

You are calling the function again and again between left/right. Maybe you should to use `cut` instead of `right` here? And actually, compare the `cut` with `left` then like you do with `right` ...

The "corrupted stack" error after fixing the first issue is because the `main()` calls the quickSort function with wrong parameters - it should be either

```
quickSort(arr, 0, size-1);
```

or

```
quickSort(arr, size); // the overload handling the -1
```

Also, the `length-length` expression in the overloaded function is relatively convoluted way to write `0`.

You can also alter the code to actually take the size as `right` but then always start at `right-1` (this is how std algorithms which take iterators usually work, allowing to pass `end()` which is after the last array item).

Comment: Ah thank you for that. We got through the error I was referring to, but now there existed another error, It says "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted." with an arrow pointing to the closing bracket of the main function

Comment: Added the cause of the corrupted stack problem ^^

Comment: Everything works fine now chief. I really appreciate your help. I still have one question though, I need to get much better at coding what shall I do?

Comment: Well, just practice and learn ... you can also try some coding practice sites, like for example Hackerrank (has a lot of tasks you can try to solve, starting with the easy ones)

Comment: I took a look at Hackerrank, and I think I am going to fall in love with it. Thank you so much.